# How to make it so that the program continues if the input is the correct attribute?

Tags: python

I'm working on code to make a bank account. I can't figure out how to make it so that if the user inputs the right passcode the options appear and if the user inputs the wrong passcode the options do not appear. Currently, the options appear no matter what the user input is.

```
class Account: #Class1
  def __init__(self, name, account_number, password, balance): #__init__ function
    self.name=name #attribute of object
    self.account_number=account_number #attribute of object
    self.password=password
    self.balance=balance #attribute of object

  def password_check(self, password):
    if str6 == password:
      return True

    else:
      return False

  def deposit(self, amount): #function to deposit money
    self.balance += amount #deposits money
    return self.balance

  def withdraw(self,amount): #function to withdraw money
    if self.balance < amount: #only executes if balance is less than amount being withdrawn
        return self.balance - amount
    self.balance -= amount #withdraws money
    return self.balance

  def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.name)
  
accounts = [Account("Fred",2528318,"Fred123",300.00),Account("John",3076427,"John456",430.00),Account("Michelle",4829302,"Michelle135",570.00),Account("Ann",2918531,"Ann789",600.00)] #objects

print("Welcome to the bank.")
while True: #loops
  def create_account():
    str2=input("What is the name of the account? ")
    str3=int(input("What would you like your account number to be?"))
    str4=input("What will your password be? ")
    str5=float(input("How much money will you deposit into the account for the initial balance? "))
    gg=Account(str2,str3,str4,str5)
    accounts.append(gg)
    return("Okay.")
  
  print("Would you like to:")
  print("1. Create an account")
  print("2. Access an account.")
  str1=input("Pick an option. ")
  if str1=="1":
    print (create_account())
  if str1=="2":
    print("Accounts: ",accounts)
    acct = (input("Which account are you working with today? ")) #choice of which account to access
    acct=[a for a in accounts if a.name==acct]
    if not acct: #executes if acct is not in accounts
      print("Unable to process. That account doesn't exist.") #error message
      continue #continues the loop
    acct = acct[0]
    str6=input("What is the password of the account? ")
    acct.password_check(str6)
    

    print("Account Number: ", acct.account_number)#prints the account number
    print("Would you like to:")
    print("1. Check the balance")
    print("2. Deposit money")
    print("3. Withdraw money")
    print("4. Quit")
    choice_of_what_to_do = input("Pick an option: ") #choice of what to do
    if choice_of_what_to_do=="1": #only executes if choice_of_what_to_do is 1
      print("Current Balance of the Account: ", acct.balance) #prints the balance

    elif choice_of_what_to_do=="2": #only executes if choice_of_what_to_do is 2
      amount=float(input("How much would you like to deposit? ")) #the amount that will be deposited
      acct.deposit(amount) #deposits the money
      print("Current Balance of the Account: ", acct.balance) #prints the balance

    elif choice_of_what_to_do=="3": #only executes if choice_of_what_to_do is 3
      amount=float(input("How much would you like to withdraw? ")) #the amount that will be withdrawn
      if acct.withdraw(amount) < 0: #only executes if the balance of the account after withdrawing the money is less than 0
        print("Unable to process. Doing this will result in a negative balance.")
      print("Current Balance of the Account: ", acct.balance) #prints the balance

    elif choice_of_what_to_do=="4": #only executes if choice_of_what_to_do is 4
      print("Okay.")
      break #ends the loop

    else: #executes if choice_of_what_to_do is not 1, 2, 3, or 4
      print("Unable to process.") #error message

    choice_to_repeat=input("Would you like to see another (or the same) account (yes or no)? ") #choice to repeat the loop or not
    if choice_to_repeat=="yes": #only executes if choice_to_repeat is yes
      print("Okay.")
      continue #continues the loop

    elif choice_to_repeat=="no": #only executes if choice_to_repeat is no
      print("Okay.")
      break #ends the loop
    
    else: #executes if choice_to_repeat is not yes or no
      print("Unable to process.") #error message
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: `password_check` is returning you True or False of whether the password matched, and you are throwing away that value.  Don't you think you need `if not acct.password_check(str6):`?  You can decide what to do if it fails, like print a message and loop around again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add condition here:

```
acct.password_check(str6)
```

Because the above code only return false when invalid passcode inputted.
For example:

```
        if acct.password_check(str6):
            print("access successful")
        else:
            break
```

Also, the function `password_check` need to modify as follow, you need to pass the password from the input and validate against the password created in the account object creation:

```
    def password_check(self, input_password):
        if input_password == self.password:
            return True

        else:
            return False
```